# question about line.split command

Tags: python, split, line

This is the txt file I need to deal with:

```
chr8    148401  153100  duplication

chr8    206001  207100  deletion

chr8    584401  589500  deletion

chr8    615101  616600  deletion

chr8    842601  843200  deletion

chr8    868901  869700  deletion
```

Basically I want to extract the two numbers, and do subtraction. My code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys

file = open('/home/xxx/sge_jobs_output/rCEU.bed','r')
for line in file.readlines():
    num1 = line.split()[1].split()[0]
    num2 = line.split()[1].split()[1].split()[0]
    num = int(num2)-int(num1)
    print num
```

I can print out num1 successfully; but num2 doesn't work. So we cannot use more than two .split consecutively?

And error is like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNV_length_cal.py", line 8, in <module>
    num2 = line.split()[1].split()[1].split()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's wrong here? I'm really confused about .split command...but i cannot find tutorial on that..thx

Comment: "num2 doesn't work" Doesn't work *how?* Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: If you want to call something for each break, you probably want to use `str.partition()` instead of `str.split()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One** split is enough!

```
>>> s="chr8    584401  589500  deletion"
>>> l = s.split()
>>> l
['chr8', '584401', '589500', 'deletion']
>>> int(l[1]) - int(l[2])
-5099
```